# How to set location path js and css file in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using ionic 3 and angular in visual studio code. I have create toggle button with 3 button on 1 row. 
This is link I have refered:

```
https://codepen.io/selfclose/pen/bVyzWX
```

When I set location path of file style.css and index.js on file following as:

MyPage.html

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"/>
  <title>Ionic Pull 2 Refresh</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/css/ionic.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="MyCtrl"> 
    <ion-content>  
      <div class="button-bar">
      <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive': isActive('breakfast')}" ng-click="setActive('breakfast')">Breakfast</a>
      <a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive': isActive('lunch')}" ng-click="setActive('lunch')">Lunch</a><a class="button" ng-class="{'button-positive': isActive('dinner')}" ng-click="setActive('dinner')">Dinner</a></div>
      <p>Result : {{active}}</p>      
    </ion-content>

  <script src='http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js'></script>
  <script  src="assets/js/index.js"> </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I set style.css on assets/css folder and index.js on assets/js folder, but it seem can not read 2 files.

How to set correct location path of css and js on ionic ?

Comment: Instead of using toggle button, you can use ion-tabs. and for showing selected tab you can use selectedIndex="2", that will show the second-page default